# Use of Enterprise Service in .NET for a transaction object that does not write to DB

Tags: .net, com+

I am looking at using the DTC in Enterprise Service for managing a transaction that i need to run. What is unusual in this transaction is that the transaction will affect a data base and a number of hardware devices that we access through a native interface. What i am curious to find out is if thisis actually possible. i.e. can i write a class that will access a hardware component perform an update and also support roll back through enterprise services? All the examples i have seen so far demonstrate a database example.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From further reading around the subject i think the answer to my question is a simple No. You cannot use the DTC for mamaging transactions to non database sources such as hardware devices.